# Can members of an Enum define their own distinct methods?

Tags: kotlin, enums

I want to use an Enum to represent a heterogenous set of types of things, each of which has its own behaviour. The language lets me add arbirary methods:

```
enum class Animal(val pk: Int) {
    Bird(1) {
        fun fly() {
            println("Flying bird")
        }
    },
    Fish(2) {
        fun swim() {
            println("Swimming fish")
        }
    },
    Axolotl(3) {
        fun fly() {
            println("Flying axolotl")
        }

        fun swim() {
            println("Swimming axolotl")
        }
    };
}
```

I could use this, e.g. in a strategy pattern. This would avoid messiness in having to make `Message` abstract:

```
data class Message(val name: String, val type: Animal)
```

I want to use an enum rather than e.g. sealed classes because there won't be instances of these types.

But I can't work out how to invoke the above methods. The below says that `fly` is an unresolved reference.

```
fun tryOut() {
    val a = Animal.Bird
    a.fly()
}
```

I'm forced to create the method on the `Animal` class itself, which isn't what I want, because not all animal types can fly.

Is it possible to use Enums this way?

Comment: No but you can use a sealed class or sealed interface with `object` children to achieve exactly this behavior. An `object` has exactly one instance so it’s almost literally what you are describing with the enum. (Enum values are instances of that enum class.) The only difference is that it wouldn’t be an `Enum<>` or have a `values()` array prepopulated for you.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. That works, and works with `when` too. I'll accept that if you answer.

Comment: If you're following the song, then shouldn't Fish come before Bird?!

Comment: I don't know which song you mean. Does it mention axolotls too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use a sealed class or sealed interface with `object` children to achieve exactly this behavior. An `object` has exactly one instance so it’s almost literally what you are describing with the enum. (Enum values are instances of that enum class.) The only behavior differences I can think of are that it wouldn’t be an `Enum<>` or have a `values()` array prepopulated for you.